# when assembling apk, it gives an error antivirus trojan on xiaomi phone

Tags: android, kotlin, apk, antivirus, trojan

When I build an application for a test, for testing on a real device, when I open it, an error occurs associated with a Trojan virus, what could be the problem? Tell me please?

[image]

this is the first time, I can't even imagine what could be the problem

Comment: You need to give more details about what you've tried for now and what are the steps you've made to arrive to the result you've posted.

Comment: How have you build your app, using Android Studio and Java/Kotlin code or using some app generator?

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the error, it's all about the false positives of the avast antivirus, some function of the application or its behavior looks malicious for avast (android: evo-gen virus) may be useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue

In Ionic Project, I resolved this issue by changing minSDKVersion from 19 to minSDKVersion: 22 in the config.xml file.

Hope this works for you :)